# Is it possible to convert a switch case into ternary condition?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a `switch case`:

```
 var rollNumValue = "1001";
 switch (someVariable) {
     case 'A':
        urlKey = 'abc/api/01';
        keyField = { rollNo: rollNumValue};
     break;
     case 'B':
        urlKey = 'abc/api/02';
        keyField = { rollNo: rollNumValue};
     break;
     default:
        urlKey = 'abc/api/03';
        keyField = { serialNumber : rollNumValue};
 }
```

I want to convert it into a ternary condition so that I can reduce the number of lines of code.

**Why?**

I have to store the code in the database.

**Edit**

```
default:
        urlKey = 'abc/api/03';
        keyField = { serialNumber : rollNumValue};
 }
```

Comment: What does storing in the database have to do with ternary conditions?

Comment: There would be better ways to reduce the number lines than using the conditional operator.

Comment: @_Emil I just want to reduce the line of code.

Comment: Well you're repeating yourself with `keyField = { rollNo: rollNumValue};`. Put it after the switch case. Especially since it's not affected by the switch.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this:

```
urlKey = (someVariable == 'A') ? 'abc/api/01' : 
             (someVariable == 'B') ? 'abc/api/02' : 'abc/api/03';
keyField = { rollNo: rollNumValue};
```

Answer (score 0):

With only `ternary` operator your code will be not readable, but you can reduce the number of code with this. Use `ternary` operator and move the `keyField = { rollNo: rollNumValue};` out from the ternary operator.

```js
var rollNumValue = "1001";
var keyField = { rollNo: rollNumValue};

var someVariable = 'A';

var urlKey = someVariable === 'A' ? 'abc/api/01' : someVariable === 'B' ? 'abc/api/02' : 'abc/api/03';

console.log(urlKey);
```

Or with property access. JavaScript lets you to access it's properties with another variable. Just use `[]` brackets syntax.

```js
var rollNumValue = "1001";
var apis = { 'A': 'abc/api/01', 'B': 'abc/api/02', otherCase: 'abc/api/03' };

var keyField = { rollNo: rollNumValue};

var someVariable = 'A';

var urlKey = apis[someVariable] || apis.otherCase;

console.log(urlKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object instead of `switch`statement, which can be easily serialized.

```
var rollNumValue = "1001",
    values = { A: 'abc/api/01', B: 'abc/api/02', default: 'abc/api/03' },
    keyField = { rollNo: rollNumValue},
    urlKey = values[someVariable] || values.default;
```

Answer (score 0):

declare object

```
var data = {A: "01", B: "02"};
```

then you can easily convert the switch like below

```
urlKey = 'abc/api/' + (data[someVariable] || "03");
keyField = { rollNo: rollNumValue};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. With the help of ES6 object destructuring you can simply do as follows;

```js
var rollNumValue = "1001",
          urlKey,
        keyField,
    someVariable;

({urlKey,keyField} = someVariable === "A" ? {urlKey: 'abc/api/01', keyField: {rollNo: rollNumValue}}
                                          : someVariable === "B" ? {urlKey: 'abc/api/02', keyField: {rollNo: rollNumValue}}
                                                                 : {urlKey: 'abc/api/03', keyField: {rollNo: rollNumValue}});

console.log(urlKey);
console.log(keyField);
```